# ReferenceError: website is not defined

Tags: jquery

I'm building an image scroller for SharePoint 2013 and am getting this error pointing to this line and I'm unsure why. I'm learning html/js as I go so I appreciate all the help.

This is the line in the code returning the error

```
var oList = website.get_lists().getByTitle(bannerListName);
```

There is more to it, but this is whats stopping it.

```
(function()
{
/********************* User Defined Variables ***************************************
**** Update the variables below to customize how the banner rotator works ***********/
var bannerListName = "Banner Rotator"; //the name of the list to pull the banner items from
var interval = 7; //time to wait before showing the next picture (in seconds)
var showPages = false; //change to false if you do not want to show the page numbers

//if you know how to write CAML you can update this string
//by default it looks for all items in the list, but you can change that here
var query = '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>';
/***********************************************************************************/

//global variables
var index = 0;
var bannerList = [];

$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
        // make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before code runs
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext',start);
                        });

function start()
{
    ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.site = ctx.get_site();
    this.website = ctx.get_web();
    var oList = website.get_lists().getByTitle(bannerListName);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(query);
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    ctx.load(collListItem);
    this.ctx.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `this.website` and not just `website`

```
this.website = ctx.get_web();   //<-- you store it in this.website, not var website
var oList = this.website.get_lists().getByTitle(bannerListName);
```

Comment: Alternatively, sometimes I also like to simply create a variable with the same name for reuse. `var website = this.website = ctx.get_web();` so that later on in the same context `website` can be used as well.

Comment: This answered my question :) But brought on my errors. I'll try and work through these now that I understand whats going on! Thank you